# Adding warning or alter message to the Access chart in the form

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to add Warning message/alert when the plot data goes beyond certain criteria in MS Access form containing chart (chart is line chart)? To make it clear I have created a plot from query in the form and the plot has average and control limit lines, now I would like to set alarm when the data set crosses the control limit set there. 
I am looking for the possibility. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well... you can obviously take the data source behind that graph, and analyze that using VBA (or even macro, if you'd like). Chart objects in MS Access are rather limited.

Comment: As a novice I have never used VBA. Searched for this and didn't find any help on the web. Any hint or advice on the matter?

Comment: This is an advanced subject, without VBA knowledge even just showing a message box would be difficult. I think the best advice I could give you is go learn VBA. However, if you really wish to try without the appropriate knowledge, you can use `DMax("MyLineField"; "MyTableOrQuery"; "ID = " & Forms!FormName![ID])` to get the highest value in the graph. You can use that in an If statement in a macro, and then use the `MessageBox` command to show a box. Bind the macro to the forms `form_current` event. Fill in the appropriate field and column names for your database.

Comment: That is great advice and I appreciate your help and codes as well as statements here. I am getting that excel and access VBA are similar. Well Ill go through videos and give it a shot.